# Flex3 - Using an image as a HSlider

Tags: apache-flex, slider

I'm using a hslider to select a range of values. However, I only have 5 values. 
The problem I'm having is that the dragging of a thumb does not look too good and the values of the thumbs are displayed in labels, beside the slider...
I was then thinking about how to improve the look of the dragging and the slider.

I came up with this: having an image that would behave like a slider. 
For example, something like this: a background image (sorry for the "drawing")

```
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |

 -/\----------------/\--------
```

With 2 thumbs (min and max values) that would stay in the middle of each box.

I don't know if my explanation is understandable. If not, let me know and I'll try to explain it in some other way =)

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skin the slider control then see:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/12/changing-a-slider-controls-thumb-skin/

or

http://proofofconcepts.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/skinning-a-flex-slider/

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for your answer.
For the first link, I'm not looking to skin the thumbs =)
For the second link, I did indeed think about skinning the slider so that the slider bar would look like an image with values inside...
But it's not really scalable... And the thumbs would not stop in the middle of each value... =(